# Can't use Express.js in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

I installed node and npm, and then I isntalled express gobally and locally. I am following this tutorial.

But when I type the command express, or express -c stylus, it asks Destination is not empty? and then it says aborting.

The package is created, though.

```
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog$ express mytestapp

   create : mytestapp
   create : mytestapp/package.json
   create : mytestapp/app.js
   create : mytestapp/public
   create : mytestapp/public/images
   create : mytestapp/public/stylesheets
   create : mytestapp/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : mytestapp/routes
   create : mytestapp/routes/index.js
   create : mytestapp/views
   create : mytestapp/views/layout.jade
   create : mytestapp/views/index.jade
   create : mytestapp/public/javascripts

   dont forget to install dependencies:
   $ cd mytestapp && npm install

abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog$ express -c stylus
destination is not empty, continue? 
aborting
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog$ express
destination is not empty, continue? 
aborting
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog$ express
destination is not empty, continue? 
aborting
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog$ cd mytestapp
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog/mytestapp$ npm install
npm WARN engine express@2.5.8: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
express@2.5.8 node_modules/express
├── qs@0.4.2
├── mime@1.2.4
├── mkdirp@0.3.0
└── connect@1.9.2 (formidable@1.0.17)

jade@1.9.2 node_modules/jade
├── character-parser@1.2.1
├── void-elements@2.0.1
├── commander@2.6.0
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── with@4.0.3 (acorn-globals@1.0.4, acorn@1.0.3)
├── constantinople@3.0.1 (acorn-globals@1.0.4)
└── transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog/mytestapp$ express -c stylus
destination is not empty, continue? 
aborting
abhishek@TiltedLines:~/blog/mytestapp$ express
destination is not empty, continue?
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by rerunning the `express` command?

Comment: You probably can ignore the prompt. There's even an option (`-f`) to force commands even when the dir is not empty

Comment: @Abhi frow where you have Express in version 2.5.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run the options as part of the single express generator that you run and not as individual calls. From your sample output you would have an app generated under `mytestapp` and then the css styling created at the level above that as you ran the `express -c stylus` command from outside of the generated `mytestapp` directory.

Try running the following in an empty directory:

```
express -c stylus mytestapp
```

This will create your app with the stylus css engine.